# switch statement - validate substrings

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement, substring

the field data has 4 acceptable types of values:

```
 j
 47d (where the first one-two characters are between 0 and 80 and third character is d)
 9u (where the first one-two characters are between 0 and 80 and third character is u)
 3v (where the first character is between 1 and 4 and second character is v).
```

Otherwise the data should be deemed invalid.

string data = readconsole();

what is the best way of validating this input?

I was considering a combination of .Length and Switch substring checks.

ie.

```
if (data == "j")

else if (data.substring(1) == "v" && data.substring(0,1) >=1 && data.substring(0,1) <=4)
....
else
   writeline("fail");
```

Comment: I know the syntax is invalid, must cast strings to ints and console.writeline().etc but you get the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression that matches the different kinds of values:

```
^(j|(\d|[1-7]\d|80)[du]|[1-4]v)$
```

Example:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(data, @"^(j|(\d|[1-7]\d|80)[du]|[1-4]v)$")) ...
```

Explanation of the regular expression:

```
^ matches the beginning of string
j matches the literal value "j"
| is the "or" operator
\d matches one digit
[1-7]\d matches "10" - "79"
80 matches "80"
[du] matches either "d" or "u"
[1-4] matches "1" - "4"
v matches "v"
$ matches the end of the string
```

Answer (score 2):

A [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) will be the most succinct way to validate such rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression:

```
^(?:j|(?:[0-7]?[0-9]|80)[du]|[1-4]v)$
```

Another option is to split by number and letter, and check the results. This is quite longer, but probably easier to maintain in the long run:

```
public bool IsValid(string s)
{
    if (s == "j")
        return true;
    Match m = Regex.Match(s, @"^(\d+)(\p{L})$");
    if (!m.Success)
        return false;
    char c = m.Groups[2].Value[0];
    int number;
    if (!Int32.TryParse(m.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.Integer,
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out number)) //todo: choose culture
        return false;
    return ((c == 'u' || c == 'd') && number > 0 && number <= 80) ||
           (c == 'v' && number >= 1 && number <= 4);
}
```

Comment: just saw the edit and it worked - Thanks! upvoted. Guffa just had the working one a few mins earlier.